# Android NDK findLibrary reaturned null

Tags: android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have created an sample project to learn ndk and run it on emulator with armeabi ABI.I have successfully created my .so file which is placed in armeabi-v7a folder inside libs.When i run the project it shows UnsatisfiedLinkage error findLibrary returned null.I explore the myproject.apk file to find whether my .so file is packed inside apk and fount that inside libs but when i explore avd using DDMS perspective i didn't fount that .so file inside data/data/package/libs/

### Brief Note

Created an app with jni folder and write basic c file and then create make file and build it as mentioned on developer site then run the android app using sdk
I find .so file inside libs folder in apk
But after installation i can't find it inside data/data/package/libs/
So I got findLibrary returned null error in System.loadLibrary("libname");
I have also tried System.load(data/data/com.example.learnndk/lib/libndk1.so)

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog  
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c  
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_OPTIM := release 
APP_PLATFORM := android-8 
APP_STL := gnustl_static 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti  
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID 
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

Please help me to find a solution..

To be precise my lib file in apk didnt get unpack into applications data directory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What lib name are you using in `System.loadLibrary`? For a library called `libndk1.so` you should be saying `System.loadLibrary("ndk1");`.

That is, no leading `lib` prefix nor the `.so` file type.

Comment: I have tried both functions..but no improvements  System.loadLibrary("ndk1") &  System.load(data/data/com.example.learnndk/lib/libndk1.so)   any suggestions..???

Answer (score 0):

You are running **armeabi** emulator. This means that in **Application.mk** you need matching

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

Answer (score 0):

It works..I forget to mention Activity name in c file..In c we must declare function as Java_Package_name_Activityname_methodName();

```
Java_com_example_learnndk_MainActivityhelloLog(arguments)
```

But i do it as Java_Package_name_methodName(); Thats y unsatisfiedLink error occurs..